# task scheduler in win 2008 won't run vbs script

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, task, scheduler

I have a batch file which call a vbs script as following:

```
cd d:
    cd D:\Application\Pentasafe\HKPentasafe\DailyLog\Deployment Code
    cscript CommandProcessing.vbs
    del /s "D:\Application\Pentasafe\HKPentasafe\DailyLog\Command Usage by Command\Tempworkspace\*.txt"
```

This batch file call this vbs (commandprocessing) thenit will delete the file in tempworkspace

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim Source, Dest

objStartFolder = "D:\Application\Pentasafe\HKPentasafe\DailyLog\Command Usage by Command\Tempworkspace"
objDestFolder = "D:\Application\Pentasafe\HKPentasafe\DailyLog\Command Usage by Command\Scripted"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

'Only one file expected.
For Each objFile in colFiles
    Source = ObjStartFolder + "\" + objFile.Name
    Dest = ObjDestFolder + "\" + objFile.Name
    wscript.echo Source
    wscript.echo Dest
Next

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Source, ForReading)

Set objFile1 = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Dest, ForWriting)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    Strline = objFile.ReadLine
    'wscript.echo Strline

    If InStr(Strline,"CHGUSRPRF") Then
    Prependtext = "CHGUSRPRF"
    wscript.echo Strline
    objFile1.WriteLine Strline
    ElseIf InStr(Strline,"STRSQL") Then
    Prependtext = "STRSQL"
    wscript.echo Strline
    objFile1.WriteLine Strline
    ElseIf InStr(Strline,"STRDFU") Then
    Prependtext = "STRDFU"
    wscript.echo Strline
    objFile1.WriteLine Strline
    ElseIf InStr(Strline,"UPDATA") Then
    Prependtext = "UPDATA"
    wscript.echo Strline
    objFile1.WriteLine Strline
    ElseIf InStr(Strline,"EZVIEW") Then
    Prependtext = "EZVIEW"
    wscript.echo Strline
    objFile1.WriteLine Strline
    ElseIf InStr(Strline,"WRKQRY") Then
    Prependtext = "WRKQRY"
    wscript.echo Strline
    objFile1.WriteLine Strline
    ElseIf InStr(Strline,"WRKUSRPRF") Then
    Prependtext = "WRKUSRPRF"
    wscript.echo Strline
    objFile1.WriteLine Strline
    ElseIf InStr(Strline, "             ") Then
    If (Prependtext <> "") Then
        objFile1.WriteLine Replace(Strline, "             ", Prependtext)
        wscript.echo Replace(Strline, "             ", Prependtext)
    else
        objFile1.WriteLine Strline   
    End If
    Else 
    Prependtext = ""
    objFile1.WriteLine Strline
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close
objFile1.Close
```

however, when i schedule this job in window server 2008.. it always won't call the vbs script. rather it skip it then do the delete job. 
I have try to run it manually by double click the batch file.. 
it run well in window xp until we upgrade to window server 2008. Anyone has any idea on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

What is the current drive when the batch file runs?  Most likely it's the C: drive.  Since you don't set D: as the current drive, CommandProcessing.vbs won't be found.  To fix it, change it to D:CommandProcessing.vbs or make D: the current drive.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the file CommandProcessing.vbs located?

In D:\Application\Pentasafe\HKPentasafe\DailyLog\Deployment Code ?

Possibly the cd command fails, because the path in the first line is not in qoutes. And then cscript can not find the script file.

Comment: thanks for pointing.. the vbs file is in the same directory of the .bat file that why i didn't put path name.